# Cannot access HTTP endpoint of a service in a Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have an akka clustered application deployed to 3 nodes via Docker swarm. One of the node exposes an HTTP endpoint. The problem now is that the HTTP endpoint cannot be accessed even though it looks as if the proper port mapping has been done.

Below is the output of running docker service ls

```
docker service ls
ID                  NAME                    MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                          PORTS
prbk5icazzw8        test_seed      replicated          1/1                 registry.me:5000/seedroute:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT      *:1600->1600/tcp, *:8000->8000/tcp
ldudkew6ym6q        test_worker1   replicated          1/1                 registry.me:5000/workerroute:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT    *:1601->1601/tcp
e2oonp28rrs3        test_worker2   replicated          1/1                 192.168.0.10:5000/workerroute:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT   *:1602->1602/tcp
pe1xzog9qw4y        registry                replicated          1/1                 registry:2                                     *:5000->5000/tcp
```

But when I login into the server running the test_seed node and do `curl localhost:8000/members` It seems the connection just hangs and I do not get a response in the return:

```
curl -v localhost:8000/members
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /members HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

using wget is the same, I get the following:

```
wget localhost:8000/members
--2019-11-30 22:34:18--  http://localhost:8000/members
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Any idea what could be wrong? In summary, I have an HTTP server that is part of application deployed via Docker swarm, and I cannot access this HTTP server, even from the node it is running on.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated!

Edit-1

Forcing the request to use 1Pv4 also did not help:

```
root@akka:~# curl -4 http://localhost:8000/members
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the following line of your curl/wget output

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
```

your system is first resolving `localhost` to `::1`, the IPv6 lookback, which is not supported by Docker at the moment.

Possible solutions are:

1. **Use 127.0.0.1**: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/members`
2. **Force IPv4**: `curl -4 http://localhost:8000/members`
3. **Disable IPv6**:  As root, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following:

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```

   Then run `sysctl -p` to apply the new settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/members
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused...I will add this to the question

Comment: Are you sure your server is still up?

Comment: Yes. I just did `docker service ls` and everything is still up!

Comment: I'm talking about the server inside the container, with `docker service ls` you can see that the container is up, but maybe the webserver inside the container failed to start. Check your logs with `docker service logs SERVICE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Bug's answer above helped, but curl was still hanging intermittently. The following option below was least flaky with swarm.

Creating an overlay network `docker network create -d overlay my-net` and in the `docker-compose.yml` file marking this network external as follows:

```
networks:
  my-net:
    external: true
```

Services including `traefik` which used this `my-net` network were now accessible via curl.